# Fetch data from graph by user as JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, arrays, json

I want to fetch data in a graph by a specific user who logged in from the same database table as JSON.

**DataBase Structure**

Table: `ets_expenses`

```
1) id
2) user_id
3) ep_name
4) ep_date
5) ep_description
6) ep_amount
```

Table 2: `ets_income`

```
1) id
2) user_id
3) einc_name
4) epinc_date
5) epinc_description
6) epinc_amount
```

**Code**

Here is where I make the DB queries:

```
  <?php require_once('config.php');
        $user_id=$_SESSION['users_id'];

        $fetchincome= "SELECT einc_date, month(einc_date) as m FROM ets_income WHERE id=$user_id,  GROUP BY month(einc_date)";
                $run1 = mysqli_query($conn, $fetchincome);
                $i=1;
                 $TOTAL_INCOME=array();
                 $TOTAL_EXPENSE=array();
                 $month=array();

                while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run1)){

                    $m=$res['m'];
                    while ($month<=12); {

                    $fetchincome1="SELECT * FROM ets_income WHERE id=$user_id,  month(einc_date)=$m";
                    $run2 =mysqli_query($conn, $fetchincome1);
                    $income=0;
                        while ($result1=mysqli_fetch_assoc($run2)){
                          $income+=$result1['einc_amount'];
                        }
                        $expense=0;

                        $fetch1="SELECT * FROM ets_expenses WHERE id=$user_id,  month(ep_date)=$m";
                        $runn =mysqli_query($conn, $fetch1);
                            while ($result=mysqli_fetch_assoc($runn)){
                                $expense+=$result['ep_amount'];
                            }
                        }
                        $TOTAL_INCOME[]=$income;
                        $month[]=$m;
                        $TOTAL_EXPENSE[]=$expense;
                    }
               ?>
            <script>
```

Here is where I handle the JSON encoding:

```
var total_ex=<?php echo json_encode($TOTAL_EXPENSE)?>;

        var l=<?php echo json_encode($month)?>;
            var config = {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                    labels: l,

                     datasets: [{
                        label: 'My income',
                        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                        borderColor: window.chartColors.blue,
                        fill: false,
                        data: <?php echo json_encode($TOTAL_INCOME)?>,
                     },
                    {
                        label: 'My expense',
                        fill: false,
                        backgroundColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
                        borderColor: window.chartColors.yellow,
                        data: total_ex,

                    }]
                },
```

Comment: can you simplify the question a bit, 

would you elaborate more about what you are going to do. are  you planning to show up a dashboard after a specific user is logged in. the dashboard is getting the feed data using json encode.

what kind of graph would you like to have?
which technology are you using in the front end?
what type of library are you planning to use for the graph?

Comment: yes exactly that's what I am doing and its line graph from chart JS and i' am creating expense income tracker

Comment: and I already have graph ready but its not fetching data user wise which is stored in same database table which I have mentioned

Comment: please take a look on WHERE statement "WHERE id=$user_id" I think i have made mistake there

Comment: usually we are going to use webservices to have the data converted into json file, from that file we can visualize the data in to the graph that you mentioned. in this case you are going to use ajax to consume the webservices and feed the data into the graph